# using posh-git with conemu

Tags: windows, terminal, console, conemu

I tried doing what the fellow at this site managed:

https://github.com/rajmenon/KB/wiki/Setup-a-ConEmu-task-for-posh-git--(w--Github-for-windows)

doing the same as he using the keybind in conemu results in

```
'`powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                                                                                                            
operable program or batch file.                                                                                                                                                


Current directory:                                                                                                                                                             
C:\Users\c                                                                                                                                                                     

Command to be executed:                                                                                                                                                        
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /C `powershell -noexit -command Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass;.$env:LocalAppData\GitHub\shell.ps1;.$env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1         


ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=1.                                                                                                                  
Press Enter or Esc to close console...
```

'`powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

typing just powershell in conemu results in a fine running powershell(x64) process, so I don't think this is a path issue. im on conemu 64 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there are stray back-tick (`) characters in those instructions. They are used to delimit code blocks in markdown, but so is putting four spaces before the code on a new line. It looks like the author tried to do both.

The fix is to ignore those back ticks at the start and end of those commands.

```
`powershell -noexit -command Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass;.$env:LocalAppData\GitHub\shell.ps1;.$env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1 -new_console:a`
```

should be:

```
powershell -noexit -command Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass;.$env:LocalAppData\GitHub\shell.ps1;.$env:github_posh_git\profile.example.ps1 -new_console:a
```

Comment: well I should know better... but so should he :) thanks bud

Comment: Apparently editing that page is open to anyone, so I have removed the back ticks from the documentation to avoid future confusion.

Comment: apparently, the whole page is deleted?

Comment: @kumar_harsh looks like it was renamed: https://github.com/rajmenon/KB/wiki/Setup-a-ConEmu-task-for-posh-git--(w--Github-for-windows)

Comment: alright, I've updated it in the question